# Writing and Reading data to EEPROM sequentially

Tags: c, embedded, avr, eeprom, atmega16

I am working on my college project which needs to store data in EEPROM of AtMega32.
I am able to write and read data at any particular location of memory. But when I try to write data sequentially form address 0 to 1023 I am getting wrong values.

Here are the functions I have written.

Function definition to read and write data

```
#include "eeprom.h"

uint8_t EEPROMRead(uint16_t uiAddress)
{
    /* Wait for completion of previous write */
    while(EECR & (1<<EEWE));
    /* Set up address register */
    EEAR = uiAddress;
    /* Start eeprom read by writing EERE */
    EECR |= (1<<EERE);
    /* Return data from data register */
    return EEDR;
}

void EEPROMWrite(uint16_t uiAddress, uint8_t ucData)
{
    /* Wait for completion of previous write */
    while(EECR & (1<<EEWE));
    /* Set up address and data registers */
    EEAR = uiAddress;
    EEDR = ucData;
    /* Write logical one to EEMWE */
    EECR |= (1<<EEMWE);
    /* Start eeprom write by setting EEWE */
    EECR |= (1<<EEWE);
}
```

Here is main function

```
static int epadr=0;
epread=EEPROMRead(epadr);      //reading from address stored in epadr
printf("%d",epread);           //printing values


if(epadr<=1023)
    {
        EEPROMWrite(epadr,high);    //writing at address stored in epadr
        epadr++;                   //increment address
    }
}

if(epadr>1023)
printf("Memory Full\n");
```

I want to store data from location 0 to 1023. Please tell what is wrong with this code.

Comment: What is the definition of the `EEAR`, `EECR`, and `EEDR` etc variables?

Comment: Where do you initialize `epadr`? Do you rely on zero init of static storage duration variables? Doing so is bad practice, particularly in embedded systems, that often have non-standard start-up code which skips zero initialization.

Comment: @Dai 'EEAR, EECR, EEDR' are registered defined to acsess EEPROM of AVR.

Comment: @Lundin I have initialized epadr like this "static int epadr=0;"

Comment: Does the bug persist if you change it to `static int epadr; epadr=0;` ?

Comment: @Lundin Yes it has no effect on output. Still getting the same output

Comment: Btw you are aware that `if(epadr<=1023)` only writes to address 0 and not from 0 to 1023, yeah? There's no loop.

Comment: @RaviSharma Can you post full main function.?

Comment: If condition is checking the value of epadr if it is less than 1023 then it will write data at corresponding location. Can you explain how it is writing data at 0 location?

Comment: @RaviSharma You are not mentioned loop here.

Comment: @Anbu.Sankar Here is full code

`a=adc_read(0);

_delay_ms(10);

a-=81;

check=a;

if (check>high)

{

 high=check;

 if(epadr<=1023)

 {

  EEPROMWrite(epadr,high);

  epadr++;

 }

}



if(epadr>1023)

drawString("Mem Full",10,250,2,BLACK);`

Comment: @Anbu.Sankar but I am incrementing epadr value after each write

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. Look up <avr/eeprom.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to define your own function for reading and writing data in internal EEPROM. AVR provide library for this purpose. Here is the sample code:-

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/eeprom.h>

int main(void)
{
    char read[5];

    eeprom_write_byte (0, '0');
    eeprom_write_byte (1, '1');
    eeprom_write_byte (2, '2');
    eeprom_write_byte (3, '3');
    eeprom_write_byte (4, '4');

    for (int count=0;count<5;count++)
    {
        read[count]=eeprom_read_byte((const uint8_t *)(count));
    }

    while (1); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't wait for the read to complete before reading `EEDR`. There's no guarantee the value will be ready to read when you read it. You need to add about a 1ms delay after setting `EERE` and before reading `EEDR`.

See the entry under [EEPROM Read/Write Procedure](http://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Permanent_Data_Storage_with_AVR_Internal_EEPROM#EEDR_.28EEPROM_Data_Register.29) for more information.